# Show that, necessarily, S = kln(\omega)

Tags: functions

I need to show that $S = f(\omega)$, plus the properties of entropy and multiplicity, necessarily implies that $S = k ln(\omega)$.
Now the properties i can see is:

$f(\omega_{1})+f(\omega_{2}) = f(\omega_{1}\omega_{2})$, which implies also that $f(1) = 0$

And we need to have that $df/d \omega > 0 $

Now, i think i need to know more about the properties of logarithm, i mean, maybe it could be the only real valued function that satisfy these properties, but i couldn't prove it.

Do you have any tip?

Answer (score 0):

since It is given that $df/d\omega>0$ this means that derivative exists,

so from the definition of a derivative

$f'(x)=\lim_ {h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x(1+\frac{h}{x}))-f(x)}{h}$

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)+f(1+\frac{h}{x})-f(x)}{h}$ $(since,f(xy)=f(x)+f(y))$

you can continue now